# How to get TopN recommendations using Matrix Factorization e.g. libFM

Tags: r, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

Being very new to recommender-systems and Matrix Factorization i was wondering how to get topN recommendations for a given user.

So far my strategy is to create all possible User/Item combinations, predict all of them and take the best N ones based on their predicted rating. This seems very inefficient to me as the number of possible combinations grows very fast.
**Question**: Is there a better method? If yes which one?

In practice my approach by works as follows:

Having data as follows (taken from `movie_lens` in R-Package libFMexe)

```
    User                     Movie Rating
  <fctr>                    <fctr>  <dbl>
       1          Toy Story (1995)      5
       1          GoldenEye (1995)      3
       2          Toy Story (1995)      4
       2        Richard III (1995)      2
```

Build all possible combinations:

```
test = data.frame(User = factor(levels = levels(dat$User),
                        rep(levels(dat$User), each = length(levels(dat$Movie)))), 
          Movie = factor(levels = levels(dat$Movie),
                         rep(levels(dat$Movie), length(levels(dat$User)))),
          Rating = 0L)

    User              Movie Rating
  <fctr>             <fctr>  <int>
1      1   GoldenEye (1995)      0
2      1   Toy Story (1995)      0
3      1 Richard III (1995)      0
4      2   GoldenEye (1995)      0
5      2   Toy Story (1995)      0
6      2 Richard III (1995)      0
```

Finally predict all user/movie combinations and take the topN ratings per User as predictions.

```
require(libFMexe)
libFM(dat, test, Rating ~ User + Movie,
               task = "r", dim = 10, iter = 500)
```

Comment: How did you end up solving this?